# Attribute price should fetch on frontend on currency change

Tags: price, module, multicurrency

By default in magento for multiple currency a conversion factor is used to convert price to particular currency, But I want there should be three static price for three currency, attribute price should get fetched in front end when selecting a currency.

Please help

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Using this `$_coreHelper->currency()` function  convert price to  according to currency type

**Base Currency code:**

```
$baseCurrencyCode = Mage::app()->getStore()->getBaseCurrencyCode();
```

**Current Currency code:**

```
$currentCurrencyCode = Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode();
```

**Get Current currency symbol:**

```
$currencySymbol = age::app()->getLocale()->currency($currentCurrencyCode)->getSymbol();
```

**Price in current currency Rate:**

```
  $_coreHelper = Mage::helper('core');

     echo $_coreHelper->currency($yourPrice),false,true); ?>
```